# forEach link not appearing as clickable when fetching from Firestore

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, foreach

I have a forEach that will be showing a row of logos from firestore. I want these to be clickable with their url, both url and logo will be in the same document.

Im able to fetch and show all the logos but they are not clickable.

This is the code I use to get the foreach to show the logos.

```
const i = query(collection(db, "built"));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(i, (querySnapshot) => {
            const team = document.querySelector('.built');

            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const docData = doc.data();
                const teams = team.appendChild(document.createElement('built'));
                teams.innerHTML = `
                <a href="">
                <img class="logo">
                    <a/>
            `;
            teams.children[0].href = docData.url;
            teams.children[1].src = docData.logo;

                console.log("Current data: ", docData);
            });
        });
```

How do I create the url to be the link, and make each logo clickable?

Comment: Why are you not setting it in the loop?

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const docData = doc.data();
    team.innerHTML += `
      <a href="${docData.url}">
        <img src="${docData.logo}" class="logo" />
      </a>
    `;
});
```

or with document.createElement and logo div wrapper

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  const docData = doc.data();
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  const logo = document.createElement('img');
  logo.src = docData.logo;

  const logoWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  logoWrapper.classList.add('logo');
  link.href = docData.url;
  logoWrapper.appendChild(logo);
  link.appendChild(logoWrapper);
  team.appendChild(link);
});
```

Comment: Haha yes sorry for the </div>

Comment: This for me didn't show the logo just the space where the logo would be, but if I take out the link the logo shows

Comment: You don't have a style on your link ? No forbidden character in your url ?

Comment: that second one is exactly what I want and is doing what I want. But now the 'logo' class isn't their I've lost the styling. I tried adding the class the the image parts and style.width..display.. to after the costs log part.

how would I re add the styling its only margin, height and display?

Comment: <img src="${docData.logo}" class="logo" /> or 
logo.classList.add('logo');

Or wrap the img in a <div class="logo">

I edit the code

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a couple of things, not sure if that is causing your issue with the link not clickable.

`'/>'` instead of `'>'` for the image ending tag and
`'</a>'` instead of `'<a/>'` for the anchor tag.

Try

```
<a href="">
   <img class="logo" />
</a>
```

Comment: Oops! Thanks must of missed that.